# MySql : SUM/COUNT on three level of related tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do some stats on my tables and I need your help.
I have three tables : "sessions", "subscriptions" and "invoices"

So a "session" can have multiple "subscribers", and each subscriber can have multiple invoices.
The goal here is to show a summarize in one query :

```
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|  Session  | Subscription count | Estimated cost sum | Invoices amount sum |
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| Session 1 |                  2 |                 15 |                  16 |
| Session 2 |                  1 |                 20 |                  20 |
| Session 3 |                  2 |                 50 |                  40 |
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

You can find corresponding SQL structure and data :

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stack_invoices`;
CREATE TABLE `stack_invoices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inscription_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `inscription_id` (`inscription_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `stack_invoices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`inscription_id`) REFERENCES `stack_subscriptions` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `stack_invoices` (`id`, `inscription_id`, `amount`) VALUES
(1, 1,  5),
(2, 1,  6),
(3, 2,  5),
(4, 3,  10),
(5, 3,  5),
(6, 3,  5),
(7, 4,  40);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stack_sessions`;
CREATE TABLE `stack_sessions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `stack_sessions` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Session 1'),
(2, 'Session 2'),
(3, 'Session 3');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stack_subscriptions`;
CREATE TABLE `stack_subscriptions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `estimated_cost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `session_id` (`session_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `stack_subscriptions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`session_id`) REFERENCES `stack_sessions` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `stack_subscriptions` (`id`, `name`, `estimated_cost`, `session_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Mister A', 10, 1),
(2, 'Mister B', 5,  1),
(3, 'Mister C', 20, 2),
(4, 'Mister D', 50, 3),
(5, 'Mister E', NULL,   3);
```

Here are my attempts : 
Showing estimated cost sum :

```
SELECT
  stack_sessions.title as session,
  SUM(stack_subscriptions.estimated_cost) as estimated_cost_sum
FROM stack_sessions
LEFT JOIN 
  stack_subscriptions 
ON
  stack_subscriptions.session_id = stack_sessions.id
GROUP BY
  stack_sessions.id
```

It is ok.

Adding subscription count :

```
SELECT
  stack_sessions.title as session,
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(subscriptions1.id) 
    FROM 
      stack_subscriptions subscriptions1 
    WHERE 
      subscriptions1.session_id = stack_sessions.id
  ) as subscriptions_count,
  SUM(stack_subscriptions.estimated_cost) as estimated_cost_sum
FROM stack_sessions
LEFT JOIN 
  stack_subscriptions 
ON
  stack_subscriptions.session_id = stack_sessions.id
GROUP BY
  stack_sessions.id
```

It is ok.

But when I want to show the sum of all invoice group by the session... It no longer work :

```
SELECT
  stack_sessions.title as session,
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(subscriptions1.id) 
    FROM 
      stack_subscriptions subscriptions1 
    WHERE 
      subscriptions1.session_id = stack_sessions.id
  ) as subscriptions_count,
  SUM(stack_subscriptions.estimated_cost) as estimated_cost_sum,
  SUM(stack_invoices.amount) as invoices_amount_sum
FROM stack_sessions
LEFT JOIN 
  stack_subscriptions 
ON
  stack_subscriptions.session_id = stack_sessions.id
LEFT JOIN
  stack_invoices
ON
  stack_invoices.inscription_id = stack_subscriptions.id
GROUP BY
  stack_sessions.id
```

With this attempt, data are correct for **subscriptions count** and **invoices amount sum** but not for **estimated cost sum**.

I tried another way :

```
SELECT
  stack_sessions.title as session,
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(subscriptions1.id) 
    FROM 
      stack_subscriptions subscriptions1 
    WHERE 
      subscriptions1.session_id = stack_sessions.id
  ) as subscriptions_count,
  SUM(stack_subscriptions.estimated_cost) as estimated_cost_sum,
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(stack_invoices.amount) as invoices_amount_sum
    FROM 
      stack_invoices
    WHERE
      stack_invoices.inscription_id = stack_subscriptions.id
  )
FROM stack_sessions
LEFT JOIN 
  stack_subscriptions 
ON
  stack_subscriptions.session_id = stack_sessions.id
GROUP BY
  stack_sessions.id
```

But MySql ask me to group by correctly and I can't find the good columns to group by.

I don't know if it is possible in one query ? Perhaps there is some SQL notion that I miss...

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the solutions might be this:

```sql
SELECT
  stack_sessions.title AS session,
  ANY_VALUE(stack_subscription_summary.subscriptions_count) AS subscriptions_count,
  ANY_VALUE(stack_subscription_summary.estimated_cost_sum) AS estimated_cost_sum,
  SUM(stack_invoices.amount) AS invoices_amount_sum
FROM
    stack_sessions
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            session_id AS session_id,
            SUM(estimated_price) AS estimated_cost_sum,
            COUNT(id) AS subscriptions_count
        FROM
            stack_subscriptions
        GROUP BY
            session_id
    ) AS stack_subscription_summary ON
        stack_sessions.id = stack_subscription_summary.session_id
    LEFT JOIN stack_subscriptions ON
        stack_subscriptions.session_id = stack_sessions.id
    LEFT JOIN stack_invoices ON
        stack_invoices.inscription_id = stack_subscriptions.id
GROUP BY
  stack_sessions.id
```

How does it solve your issue?

Your code stopped working because you were doing `SUM` of nondistinct rows - meaning you added a value of subscription more then once if it had more invoices.

That means you need to group some of your data in a subquery.
I'm showing this on grouping subscription data (therefore getting their summaries), but the probably more elegant way (and probably faster) would be to group invoice data like this:

```sql
SELECT
  stack_sessions.title AS SESSION,
  COUNT(stack_subscriptions.id) AS subscriptions_count,
  SUM(stack_subscriptions.estimated_cost) AS estimated_cost_sum,
  SUM(stack_invoices_summary.amount) AS invoices_amount_sum
FROM
  stack_sessions
  LEFT JOIN stack_subscriptions ON
    stack_subscriptions.session_id = stack_sessions.id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  
      inscription_id AS inscription_id,
      SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
      stack_invoices
    GROUP BY
      inscription_id
  ) AS stack_invoices_summary ON
    stack_invoices_summary.inscription_id = stack_subscriptions.id
GROUP BY
  stack_sessions.id
```

I haven't tested this on your data, so let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks janmpeterka !
Both solutions works. The second one is more clear for me.
I'll dig into the "ANY_VALUE" of your first solution just in case.

Comment: Great to hear!
`ANY_VALUE` picks randomly from grouped data. In this case, all data is the same (only possibly duplicated because of LEFT JOIN after), so it doesn't matter which you pick.
Also will be grateful for upvote :)